# Who took the most wickets in 1 over in cricket?

Tags: cricket, trivia, wicket

Who took the most wickets in 1 over in cricket? I got to know that Muhammad  Aamir is not the right answer; there is someone else who took more wickets than him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In international cricket, the most taken by a bowler in a single over is 4 wickets.

This has happened six times in Test cricket:

1. Maurice Allom - For England vs New Zealand in 1929
2. Ken Cranston - For England vs South Africa in 1947
3. Fred Titmus - For England vs New Zealand in 1965
4. Chris Old - For England vs Pakistan in 1978
5. Wasim Akram - For Pakistan vs the West Indies in 1990
6. Andy Caddick - For England vs the West Indies in 2001

and twice in ODI matches:

- Lasith Malinga (Sri Lanka) took 4 wickets in an over in an ODI match against South Africa in 2007.
- Mohammed Siraj (India) took 4 wickets in an over in an ODI match against Sri Lanka in 2023. This was also the final of the Asia Cup 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Malinga's 4 wickets came across 2 overs.

Chaminda Vaas, however, took 4 wickets in an over against Bangladesh, including a hat-trick off the first 3 balls. The 4th wicket came off the 5th ball.

Comment: The first part of this is a comment on another answer.  The second part is additional information.

Answer (score -1):

Neil Wagner [has taken 5](https://www.nzherald.co.nz/sport/cricket-wagner-takes-five-wickets-in-an-over/4ZKUICEPHBKBTUPCNGRZBBQNGM/) in an over against Wellington in 2011, the first and only time this has happened in first-class cricket.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. Can you add a source to your answer?

Comment: Who was he playing for when he took them and can you give a date?

Comment: He was playing for Otago at the time. This is well documented within NZ cricket.

You can watch it here 

https://youtu.be/B5eGlA6YvkA

Comment: Can also read one of the original stories here from the NZ herald. 

https://www.nzherald.co.nz/sport/cricket-wagner-takes-five-wickets-in-an-over/4ZKUICEPHBKBTUPCNGRZBBQNGM/

Answer (score -2):

Muhammad Sami from Pakistan also take 4 wickets in an over against New Zealand 2003.

At 1:45, they give an accounting of the 36th over; WW00WW.  Three wickets are taken by bowling, and one is caught.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference showing the exact match this happened in? There seems to be no mention of this on his Wikipedia page.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I believe I found the result (trivial YouTube search brought this up, and it matches the specifics).